# Regex After Two Points

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

After outputting **lsb_release -a** in Linux, I just want to print the distributor ID on the screen.
Example output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I just want to print the distributor id, that is, just the text "Ubuntu".
I need to do this in bash, just with sed or grep. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure `bash`, no external programs needed (Aside from `lsb_release`, of course):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
re="^Distributor ID:[[:space:]]+(.*)"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done < <(lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command with `awk`:

```
lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep "Distributor ID" | awk '{print $3}'
```